# What is the difference between a COM DLL and a VC++ MFC DLL?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com

when we will say a dll is COM dll and when we will say a dll is vc++-MFC dll ?

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A COM DLL exposes one or more COM objects. For more on COM DLLs please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wad1c0e(VS.80).aspx

Comment: If i am developing MFC dll , how can i access from the visual studio c#?
If i am developing COM dll , how can i access from the visual studio C#?

Comment: COM objects can be referenced through the Add Reference dialog. For regular native DLLs you need to use p/invoke, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx

Comment: then what is the use of type lib converter ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is wrong . Actually MFC is one of the ways to create a com DLL along with ATL